# I need to grep data from specific number of rows, like row 1, 6

Tags: linux, unix

I need to grep a word from row number 1, then 6, then 11 & so on.

```
1- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-01 to China NETACT,KOL1bds001,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.6 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
2- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-01 to China NETACT,KOL1bds001,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.6 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
3- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-01 to China NETACT,KOL1bds001,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.6 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
4- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-01 to China NETACT,KOL1bds001,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.6 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
5- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-01 to China NETACT,KOL1bds001,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.6 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
6- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-02 to China NETACT,KOL1bds002,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.7 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
7- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-02 to China NETACT,KOL1bds002,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.7 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
8- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-02 to China NETACT,KOL1bds002,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.7 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
9- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-02 to China NETACT,KOL1bds002,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.7 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
10- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-02 to China NETACT,KOL1bds002,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.7 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
11- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-03 to China NETACT,KOL1bds003,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.8 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
12- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-03 to China NETACT,KOL1bds003,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.8 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
13- IntraPOP,I'NAL,Active,KOL BE-DS-03 to China NETACT,KOL1bds003,VCFlexA-X5,144.15.21.8 ,341,China NetAct,NA,143.14.45.144,340,
```

Comment: If that is a CSV file, then use php's CSV functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: 1) format your code please; 2) could you be more specific about "a word" (desired output ?); 3) have you tried by yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can be easily used to grab every fifth line starting with the first:

`cat file | awk '!((NR-1)%5)' | grep ...`

This takes the line number, subtracts 1, and verifies that it is divisible by 5.

Comment: Thanks Rob .. will check & let you know :)

Comment: Thanks .. Working FIne .. (y)